# How can I Set "cookieName" attribute of the "sessionState" XML element in my web.config programatically

Tags: .net, asp.net, session, session-state

Multiple applications are sharing the same session cookie at the moment and I don't want this to be the case, however, I would like to set the value in code rathr than hardcode a value using the web.config.

Does anyone know how thi can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can place application specific config files in each application folder and then reference them like this in the web.config:

```
<authentication configSource="auth.config"></authentication>
```

In each auth.config, you can then do what you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="app1_login.aspx" timeout="60" name=".APP1" path="/app1" />
</authentication>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how you get it: 
[How to programmatically get session cookie name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739537/how-to-programmatically-get-session-cookie-name)
but you can surely set it as well..