# How to programmatically get session cookie name?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The default cookie name for the Session Id in ASP.NET is `ASP.NET_SessionId`. It's also possible to change this name to something else like `<sessionState cookieName="FooBar" />`.

Is there a member to easily access this name like with `FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName`?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Taking into account that you say that you set an different name for the cookie on the web.config then I'd say you could read the cookie name from there

```
SessionStateSection sessionStateSection =
  (System.Web.Configuration.SessionStateSection)
  ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");

string cookieName =  sessionStateSection.CookieName;
```

Comment: Ok but what about the case where it *doesn't* get changed? Will this return the default value of `ASP.NET_SessionId` as well?

Comment: Yes, when you didn't change it you get "ASP.NET_SessionId"

Comment: Aren't there really no more straightforward ways? Has Microsoft really not think of a class to help with that?

Comment: @SergeProfafilecebook - It seems very straightforward and easy to work with to me.

Comment: `CookieName` will be defaulted to `"ASP.NET_SessionId"` if nont is specified in the config as it has a `ConfigurationPropertyAttribute` of `[ConfigurationPropertyAttribute("cookieName", DefaultValue = "ASP.NET_SessionId")]` so there is no need to do your own setting/checking